# Laravel 6 Use a custom Hasher during migration from CakePHP 2.x

Tags: laravel, lumen

We are migrating applications from CakePHP 2.X but we need to implement our mobile API's before the migration.  I have followed all the items I could find but they all seem to be for v5 or less. No matter what I do Hash::make() still results in a Bcrypt password.

I really want to 2 birds one stone with having this allow sha1() login and update to Bcrypt upon login but we havent implemented on CakePHP 2.x successfully.  So I need to get the Hasher working or a workaround. I know I can just Hash manually in the model but that doesnt allow Auth to work.

Any help would be appreciated

app.php config file

```
Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
//Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\CustomHashServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
```

CustomHashServiceProvider.php

```
    <?php
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider;
use App\Libs\CustomHash\CustomHasher as CustomHasher;

class CustomHashServiceProvider extends HashServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('hash', function () {
            return new CustomHasher;
        });
    }
}
```

CustomHasher.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Lib\CustomHash;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher as HasherContract;

class CustomHasher implements HasherContract {

    /**
     * Hash the given value.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return array   $options
     * @return string
     */
    public function make($value, array $options = array()) {
        //I have custom encoding / encryption here//
        //Define your custom hashing logic here//
        return sha1(env('SEC_SALT').$value);
    }

    /**
     * Check the given plain value against a hash.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @param  string  $hashedValue
     * @param  array   $options
     * @return bool
     */
    public function check($value, $hashedValue, array $options = array()) {
        return $this->make($value) === $hashedValue;
    }

    /**
     * Check if the given hash has been hashed using the given options.
     *
     * @param  string  $hashedValue
     * @param  array   $options
     * @return bool
     */
    public function needsRehash($hashedValue, array $options = array()) {
        return false;
    }

    public function info($hashedValue): array {
        return $hashedValue;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I refactored based on @Mdexp answer to this .... but I found out the Configs are ignored unless added in app.php on Lumen

New app.php

```
/*
* Application Service Providers...
*/
App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
// App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\Sha1HashServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
```

Sha1HashServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class Sha1HashServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register() {
        //
    }

    public function boot() {
        $this->app->make('hash')->extend('sha1', function () {
            // Just create the driver instance of the class you created in the step 1
            return new \App\Lib\Sha1Hash\Sha1Hasher;
        });
    }
}
```

Sha1Hasher.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Lib\Sha1Hash;

use Illuminate\Hashing\AbstractHasher;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher as HasherContract;
use RuntimeException;

class Sha1Hasher extends AbstractHasher implements HasherContract {

    public function __construct(array $options = []) {

    }

    public function make($value, array $options = []) {
        $hash = sha1(env('SEC_SALT').$value);
        if ($hash === false) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Sha1 hashing not supported.');
        }
        return $hash;
    }

    public function check($value, $hashedValue, array $options = []) {

        return ($this->make($value) == $hashedValue)?true:false;
    }

    public function needsRehash($hashedValue, array $options = array()): bool {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your Update really helped me. Just one thing to add that for Lumen I had to add config/hashing.php file. Then I had to configure it in bootstrap/app.php.

Comment: I achieved my goal with your comment in Update and the answer given by @mdexp both. Thanks to both of you guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the default `HashServiceProvider` and register a new driver into it. It would also make the switch back from sha1 to bcrypt even quicker once you completed the transitioning phase.

1) You have have to create a class which extends the `Illuminate\Hashing\AbstractHasher` or at least implements the `Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher`. Take a look at the current Bcrypt driver implementation as a reference [on GitHub](https://github.com/illuminate/hashing/blob/master/BcryptHasher.php).
The `CustomHasher` class you provided should work just fine as a driver, I would just rename it to avoid confusion with naming.

2) Now you can register the hash drivers in a service provider like:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->app->make('hash')->extend('sha1', function () {
        // Just create the driver instance of the class you created in the step 1
        return new YourCustomSha1Hasher();
    });
}
```

3) Then in your `config/hashing.php` file, set the driver to `'sha1'` (must be equal to the first parameter of the `extend` function call.

4) It should work straight out of the box, and to choose a different hashing driver, just change the `config/hashing.php` configuration file with the driver that you want to use for hashing.

**Note:** the whole code hasn't been tested, but I looked through the source code to come up with this solution that should work. Just comment anything isn't working as expected so I can fix my answer.